# Implementing a Desktop TabView in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, windows, desktop, maui

I just got started with .NET MAUI. From the get-go I'm already having difficulty making the Windows deployment look like a typical Windows desktop app, which I find odd as it seemed to be largely marketed as achieving a native look on each platform.

I'm just trying to implement a TabView that look like this, for the Desktop version of the app - this is from the WinUI gallery, which to my understanding MAUI uses:

[image]

Or alternatively, like the classic WinForms one:

[image]

But unfortunately any Google search related to .NET MAUI seems to either focus on mobile deployments and aesthetics (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/tabbedpage):

[image]

Is it at all feasible to achieve the desktop aesthetics for the desktop version of a MAUI app? So far it feels like MAUI is actually a mobile UI framework that happens to run on desktops.

Comment: Have you actually tried TabbedPage on Windows? "On Windows, the list of tabs appears at the top of the screen, and the page content is below. Each tab consists of a title." suggests you get tabs at the top of the screen.

Comment: What "difficulty" are you having specifically?  It doesn't appear that you've actually tried anything yet.  30 minutes spent building a sample would probably give you a lot more answers than anything we can tell you.

Comment: @MartinHonnen yeah I have - as linked in the Microsoft documentation. The result is, well, indeed a TabbedPage - however it looks like the one you see in mobile apps. Unlike the first or second screenshot, which is the typical desktop TabbedPage you see in, desktop apps (e.g. a web browser). Also it takes the entire ContentPage - I may want to have multiple TabbedPages inside, say, another TabbedPage, etc.

Comment: @Jason the difficulty is that if you follow Microsoft's documentation on `TabbedPage`, the result is an entire page with tabs styled like a mobile app (last screenshot), which does not look like e.g. WinForms' TabbedPage which can be contained and placed anywhere within the Form. What else is there to try, other than the official documentation itself? There is literally a Microsoft page on "how to use `TabbedPage`" - why would I be trying anything else than that? Sounds exactly like what I should be trying - and I did - and it looks exactly like a mobile app instead of the first two images.

Comment: Your question did not specify that your main concern was the fact that it fills the page.  Pages in MAUI consume the entire screen (or window).  A TabView can be placed anywhere within a page. Several component vendors offer TabView controls for MAUI, or you can wait and see if a community version becomes available (there is one in the XF Community Toolkit)

Comment: The one in the XF Community MAUI Compatible Toolkit fails miserably ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

Can it be done?  Possibly.

Is it supported out-of-the-box in Maui?  No.

---

First, the close button ("X") on tabs is not supported in Maui.  This is due to the mobile-first nature of Maui.  Adding and removing tabs is possible, but only through hacks.

Also the look-and-feel will carry the mobile-first design hints.  Specifically the active tab will have an underline instead of the traditional raised tab outline.

Finally there's the issue of placing the tabs on a specific part of the UI vs having the tabs for the entire UI.  Maui only supports tabs for the entire window as opposed to a portion of the window.  This doesn't seem to be an issue for your use-case, though.

It should be mentioned that there are third-party vendors that provide additional Maui controls, but for tabs they seem to match the same design philosophy as the built-in Maui controls.  Alternatively you can create custom controls that will allow you to do design things as you like, but you will quickly find yourself implementing many platform-specific implementations.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if you use [UraniumUI TabView](https://enisn-projects.io/docs/en/uranium/latest/themes/material/components/TabView)

There is an example in the GitHub Repository that demonstrates how to build closable tabs.

View: https://github.com/enisn/UraniumUI/blob/5d62ce2e18af704e6fea10d0a89e0ef829c7327a/demo/UraniumApp/Pages/TabViews/WebTabViewPage.xaml#L29-L55

ViewModel: https://github.com/enisn/UraniumUI/blob/develop/demo/UraniumApp/ViewModels/TabViews/WebTabViewModel.cs

[image]